# PostGIS topology: creation of topogeometry polygons for simplification

Tags: postgis, topology, postgis-2.3

I am using PostGIS topology to manage a geologic mapping project.

My basic topology is defined by linework. The interstital polygons are meaningful, but can be constructed simply from lines and attribute data stored in points. I then generate the polygons "on the fly" from my linework, spatially joined to point attribute data. This allows me to keep the polygons in sync with my linework.

This works rather well, but it means that the polygons are Geometry objects, not Topogeometries. So I can't simplify the layer in a topologically-aware manner using `St_Simplify`.
I would also like to make larger polygons that are supersets of individual polygons based on attribute data, to allow generalized "dissolve" of map units.

Basically, it seems like I am looking for the equivalent of `ST_GetFaceGeometry` that returns a topologically-defined element. Perhaps `topology.AddFace` is what I need, but going from line topogeometries through polygonal geometries and *back to* a different topological representation of polygons seems confusing.

Plus I am not sure how to translate these `face_id`s to topogeometries and what happens if the linework is edited and `edge_id`s change – can I easily delete bad faces?

Any guidance from someone who has dealt with similar situations?